# How to force React.memo render component only once (on initial load)?

Tags: reactjs, render, react.memo

Inside my parent component I have a child component that I need to render only once - at the very beginning. Because the data inside wont ever change until next page reload. What I try to do is somehow force React.memo to prevent rendering of this child component:

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {

    const ChildComponent = React.memo(({items}) => {
        const { param1, param2, param3 } = items;
        ...
        return (<Box>..</Box>);
    }, (prev, nxt) => true); // Here I try to force no render
    
    return (<Box>
          <ChildComponent items={{
             param1: 'some val..',
             param2: 'some val..',
             param3: 'some val..',
          }} />
          ...
       </Box>);
}
```

But child component still re-renders on each parent state change. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure but can you try to put the definition of the ChildComponent outside of ParentComponent ?

Comment: yes, I just did it, haunted by the same doubts, but the behavior is the same :-(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, defining a component inside another component is a bad practice, because

1. Performance issue, as you are experiencing
2. You can't reuse the component --> poor scalability
3. By changing the child component, you have to update the source code of the parent component and vice versa --> easy to introduce side effects

So to make your life easier, extract the `ChildComponent`.

```
const ChildComponent = props => {
  return (
    <Box>
      {/* do whatever you like */}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default memo(ChildComponent);
```

```
const ParentComponent = props => {
  const items = {
    param1: 'some val..',
    param2: 'some val..',
    param3: 'some val..',
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <ChildComponent 
        items={items} 
        // You can also pass other props from the ParentComponent, in case ChildComponent needs it
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: yes, meanwhile I extracted the component (I know it's better..) but the behavior remained the same. And in accordance with React.memo documentation there should be no difference in behavior even in cases when component is inside..

Answer (score 1):

There are few you can achieve this, of course by using memoization. But first of all I suggest you to move `ChildComponent` definition outside of the `ParentComponent`.
Both ways require you to wrap `ChildComponent` in React.memo, like you did, so that part is okay.

First way is to be sure that value(reference) for `items` prop is stable, if you want to avoid unnecessary rerenders of child componnet. So the solution would be to wrap `items` objectin useMemo and to compute it only once so reference become stable.

Second way is to use second parameter for React.memo function, and to pass custom `isEqual` function in order to determine when your prop has changed, eg to perform deep equality check on subsequent values for `items` prop so you can avoid unnecessary rerenders. More about this can be found here [react memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)